# How to choose path to a file rather than uploading the file?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to POST a string which is the path to a file rather than uploading the file (multipart).

This code uploads the file:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/index")
    public void singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

     .
     .
    }


<form method="POST" action="index" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is used to upload a file, but I just want to obtain the path to a file. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean local path from your machine? But how will that work with a web application?

Comment: Yes local.path..

Comment: I think you need a javascript hack... A way to post just the file name

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need path of the file which is lying on remote machine ?

Comment: @SariqShaikh I want to read it in chunks and store the file in a db

Comment: @nar-007 your server will be running on separate machine and the web page you will access from another machine right ? Or it will be on the same machine itself, if there are two different machine you can not read file.

Comment: It will be on the same machine for now.. just wanted to select a file and get its local path..

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript hack like

```
var form = document.getElementById(myFormID);
form.addActionListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from default submission
  //get the path from your input, and submit that instead
});
```